# LSTM and CNN implementation for sequence of images

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement a CNN network + LSTM to be able to predict the class based on the sequence of images. My X-train shape is (2560, 250, 250, 3). Images' size is 250.250.3, and each image sequence includes 256 images (so I have 10 image sequences). I defined time-steps to be 256, channels (features) to be 3.
This is a part of my code:

```
X_data = np.reshape(X_data, (2560, 250, 250, 3))
Y_data = np.reshape(Y_data, (2560, 1))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'), input_shape=(None, 250, 250,3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.5)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPool2D(pool_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_data, Y_data, verbose=1, epochs=epochs, callbacks=callbacks)
```

And I get this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (32, 250, 250, 3)
```

When I use `input_shape=(None, 256, 250, 250,3)` I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 256, 246, 246, 64)
```

What is the problem with `input_shape` and how can I give the network the desired input()

Comment: for debugging, pls provide the code and data source for 'X_data'.

Comment: You need to have  a time axis in `X_data`. The shape must be like `( num_samples , time_steps , W , H , C )`.

Comment: I have also tried  X_data = np.reshape(X_data, (10, 256, 250, 250, 3)) but I get an error in incorrect input shape again.

Comment: X_data is a NumPy array that consists of image slices with (250, 250, 3) size. The number of all images is 2560 which I want to split into 10 sequences.